# How do I programmatically select row in Qtable in Quasar correctly

Tags: quasar

I want to select a row in a Qtable with just the row-key field (not the entire row data)
so far I am able to make the checkbox toggle when I use the row-key
this.selected = [{"name":"Eclair"}]
but I expected that the entire row data would populate into the selected object, it does not.
Go to the codepen below, first try clicking on the checkbox and note the stringified data at the bottom of the screen,

then

click on the button, and note that the stringified data is not the whole row.
codepen
https://codepen.io/jniumata/pen/YzVWoQO

So my question is, how can I programmatically select a row with just the row-key field, AND get the entire row data into the array.
(note: I don't want to have to pass the entire object, just the row-key )

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  methods: {
    onChangeSelect (details) {
      console.log('details: ', details)
      // parse details and make a request.... 
    },
    testMethod () {
      if(this.selected.length > 0) {
        this.selected = [];
      } else {
        this.selected = [{"name": "Eclair"}];  
      }
      
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      selected: [],
      columns: [
        {
          name: 'desc',
          required: true,
          label: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          field: row => row.name,
          format: val => `${val}`,
          sortable: true
        },
        { name: 'calories', align: 'center', label: 'Calories', field: 'calories', sortable: true },
        { name: 'fat', label: 'Fat (g)', field: 'fat', sortable: true },
        { name: 'carbs', label: 'Carbs (g)', field: 'carbs' },
        { name: 'protein', label: 'Protein (g)', field: 'protein' },
        { name: 'sodium', label: 'Sodium (mg)', field: 'sodium' },
        { name: 'calcium', label: 'Calcium (%)', field: 'calcium', sortable: true, sort: (a, b) => parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10) },
        { name: 'iron', label: 'Iron (%)', field: 'iron', sortable: true, sort: (a, b) => parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10) }
      ],
      data: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          sodium: 87,
          calcium: '14%',
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 129,
          calcium: '8%',
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          sodium: 337,
          calcium: '6%',
          iron: '7%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 413,
          calcium: '3%',
          iron: '8%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          sodium: 327,
          calcium: '7%',
          iron: '16%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          sodium: 50,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '0%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          sodium: 38,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '2%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          sodium: 562,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '45%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          sodium: 326,
          calcium: '2%',
          iron: '22%'
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          sodium: 54,
          calcium: '12%',
          iron: '6%'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.1/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.14.3/dist/quasar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.14.3/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>



<!--
  Forked from:
  https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#Example--Single-selection
-->
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-table
      title="Programmatically select row (click button below)"
      :data="data"
      :columns="columns"
      row-key="name"
      selection="single"
      :selected.sync="selected"
      @selection="(details) => onChangeSelect(details)"
    ></q-table>
    <div class="row justify-start">
                  
      <q-btn  label="I like eclairs" @click="testMethod" color="primary" class="q-mt-sm" />
               </div>
    <div class="q-mt-md">
      Selected: {{ JSON.stringify(selected) }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but you could try this

```
this.selected = this.data.filter(row => row.name == "Eclair")
```